# Button working on second click android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a button in my Fragment. Which supposed to turn into R.drawable.role_button_pressed then i press it or if my button is already pressed it supposed to turn into original R.drawable.role_button then i press it. But then i am pressing my button it need to be pressed twice to change it state.

My xml looks like this:

```
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/role"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_role_buttons_top"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_role_buttons_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_role_button_bot"
        android:text="@string/jungle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/role_mid_lookingfor"
        android:background="@drawable/role_button" />
```

and on click method

```
 boolean isPressed = true;

 Button rolebutton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.role);

 rolebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isPressed){
                rolebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.role_button_pressed);
                isPressed=true;
            }else if(isPressed==true){
                rolebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.role_button);
                isPressed=false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: your `else if` can be replaced by just `else`

Comment: but it makes no difference

Comment: Yep it does. It is faster! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong default boolean in the first place.
I assume the starting resource is `R.drawable.role_button`.

Change `isPressed` to false and put it into your clickListener, because it's not pressed right?

And I suggest you to use a better shortcut in your if else

```
rolebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    boolean isPressed = false;

    public void onClick(View v) {

   rolebutton.setBackgroundResource(isPressed ? R.drawable.role_button : R.drawable.role_button_pressed));
   isPressed = !isPressed;
}
}
```

Comment: it's still need to press twice :( maybe it's a bug ?

Comment: @D1's What is the default resource of the button? Can you post the xml?

Comment: XML posted in my question ->  android:background="@drawable/role_button"

Comment: @D1's See my edit. Put the boolean into your clicklistener